# Getting error: "Objects are not valid as a React child" on array rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a simple task. Rendering contents of an array:

```
const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);   // an array to begin with


handleFetch = () => {
   ...
   ...
   const obj = resp.data.comments;
   const new_array = new Array();
   new_array.push(obj);
   setComments(new_array);
   ...
}


return (

    {comments.forEach(comm => <p>{comm.post}</p>)}
);
```

comments (`resp.data.comments`) come in as an array of objects:

```
comments = [{'post': 'something', 'timestamp': 'some time'}]
```

Error output I'm getting:

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {post, timestamp}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` (But I'm using an array. An array of objects)

Comment: these two steps: `const new_array = new Array();
   new_array.push(obj);` are not necessary.. it will create a nested array

Comment: I've tried to go without it but got same error. This is what I did before:
`setComments(obj);`

Comment: Replace forEach with map. ForEach does not return anything whereas map will return you an array with items that needs ti be rendered

Comment: `.forEach()` returns `undefined`. Also, you've wrapped your `.forEach()` in `{}` but without `<> </>`, causing it to be treated as an object initializer. So I suspect your `return` is returning `{ undefined: undefined }`, thus the reason for the error message.

Comment: `obj = resp.data.comments;` makes no sense. I would guess `data.comments` is an array by itself and not a single comment Object. `log` it and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `resp.data.comments` is an array, you can directly set to it to state comments using `setComments(resp.data.comments)` and use `Array.prototype.map` function in jsx to render.

```
const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);   // an array to begin with


handleFetch = () => {
   ...
   ...
   setComments(resp.data.comments);
   ...
}


return (
<>
    {comments.map(comm => <p>{comm.post}</p>)}
</>
);
```

Comment: Mark has mentioned in his question. comments (resp.data.comments) come in as an array of objects: the data as comments = [{'post': 'something', 'timestamp': 'some time'}]

Comment: Right. I'm voting up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.map()` to return the value. So you can fix like this:

```
return (
  <>
    {comments.map((comm, index) => <p key={index}>{comm.post}</p>)}
  </>
);
```

Comment: Why the need for `key` prop is true, this has nothing to do with the problem, and therefore is not a valid answer. Should have been a *comment*

Comment: I've read it multiple times, and still, your "answer" has nothing to do with the problem. Trust me, I've been doing React for years.

Comment: The problem is using `forEach` on `return`. You make sure using `forEach` like this work well?

Comment: This is indeed a part of the problem, but not the root cause. See the other answer for the actual problem. The iterated data is not an Array of Objects but an Array of a single Array of Objects

Comment: I saw. But why you told my answer `nothing to do`?

Comment: I used the wrong words, please forgive me ‎